# head tag repeating in body with ajax call on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to ajax and I'm practicing a bit but I keep getting this kinda error which I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I am at the index page and I want to load another page `body` with ajax

for example:

localhost:3000/main/index

I want to load:

localhost:3000/main/about

currently I have this

```
$('#site-nav').find('li:eq(1)').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax('/main/about', { 
    success: function(response) {
      $('body').html(response);
    },
    error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
      alert('Error: ' + errorType + ' with message: ' + errorMessage);
    },
    timeout: 5000,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('body').fadeOut(1000);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

when I do that, my body is repeated with the `<head>...</head>` stuff and it also freezes for like 2 seconds.

thanks!

edit:

this is what the body looks like

```
<body>

  <div id="overlay"></div>

  <header id="site-header" class="header section light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="logo" class="col-29 no-padding">
          <h1 class="site-title"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/main/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="header-widgets" class="col-7">
          <!-- start social icons -->
          <!-- To be partial -->
          <nav id="header-social" class="text-right">
            <a href="#" class="icon circle tooltip" title="Like us on facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="icon circle tooltip" title="Follow us on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="icon circle tooltip" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
          </nav>
          <!-- start site navigation -->
          <%= render partial: 'shared/main_nav' %>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main id="main">

    <%= yield %>

  </main>

  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="footer-grass">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>


  <footer id="site-footer">
    <section id="footer-widgets" class="section dark">
      <%= render partial: 'shared/pre_footer' %>
    </section>

    <section id="footer-bottom" class="section dark">
      <%= render partial: 'shared/footer' %>
    </section>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: How does your about file looks like?

Comment: In question you mention that you want to load: localhost:3000/home/about while in code you have: `/main/about`. Are you sure that code you've posted is correct? Also, can you please post the code of your `about` method from controller?

Comment: @Surya I am at the localhost:3000/home/index but I want to load the localhost:3000/home/about `body`

Comment: @Johhan: But in code you have this: `$.ajax('/main/about'`, shouldn't it be `home/about` instead? Hence I asked if the code you have posted is correct?

Comment: @Surya ah sorry, yes it's main/about, I'm used to home/... instead.

Comment: @NikitaSingh I added how my master layout looks like. I'm trying to change what the `<%= yield %>` is showing with ajax.

Comment: Can you post code of `about` method from home controller?

Comment: @Surya if you mean in my `home_controller.rb` it's just a simple `def about end`